# For loop comparing Java BigDecimals

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, compare, bigdecimal

I need the loop to repeat as long as `BigDecimal d` is greater than  0. I have tried two following methods and neither of these methods seem to be working. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
for (d.compareTo(z) < 0 ; ) {

}

for (BigDecimal d>0) {

}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate language for better exposure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform the greater than operation you have to use compareTo() method.

```
 for(d.compareTo(new BigDecimal("0"))>0; ){  //Your code }
```

Example :

```
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("10");
        if(d.compareTo(new BigDecimal("0"))>0)
            System.out.println("true");
        //this evaluates to true
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, "Syntax error on token ">", ; expected" is an error on the '>' symbol and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean" is an error on the second '0'.

Comment: Works fine! You must me doing something wrong. Which language are you using, tag that with the question please.